# How to set selected extjs combo value to another combobox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, extjs, combobox

I have two `Extjs Comboboxes`

```
var cb1 = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Combobox1',
    width: 100,
    listeners:{
         scope: this,
         'select': this.reset
    }
});
var cb2 = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Combobox2',
    width: 100,
    baseParams: { loadInitial: true, cb1Val: this.cb1.getValue() } // Here I want to get selected value of cb1
    listeners:{
         scope: this,
         'select': this.reset
    }
});
```

I am using `this.cb1.getValue()` to get selected value of `cb1` but I am getting blank value here.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I think combo 2 is not able to get value of combo 1 as its not loaded while you are calling its value in baseParams. I would recommend this approach in your case -

```
    var cb1 = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        fieldLabel: 'Combobox1',
        width: 100,
        **id : "combo_1",**  // ID property added 
        listeners:{
             scope: this,
             'select': this.reset
   } });

// Previous code 
...

    listeners : {
        select : function(combo, rec, rind) {
             var combo2_val = Ext.getCmp("id_of_combo_1").getValue();
    }
```

Here, on the select renderer of second combo, the value of first should be set in `combo2_val`. To be more precise, you can also set default value for combo 1. Instead of using ID, you can directly use variable cb1 directly.

Hope this should give you a way.

Comment: But I want to pass selected value of cb1 to the base Parameter of cb2 when cb2 is loaded. The above approach sets it in select listener of cb2.